# force refresh of external libraries not working

Tags: pycharm

I have python project within a virtualenv. I opened it in pycharm.

Later i have installed some packages using pip from inside the virtualenv but not from pycharm rather from the commandline directly.

But in pycharm > settings > python interpreter : it does not show the package which i just installed from outside pycharm.

I tried to select another interpreter and come back, still its not showing the package installed from outside pycharm.

I have restarted pycharm still no luck.

Any idea how to refresh python packages inside pycharm

Answer (score 7):

Try **Settings | Project ... | Project Interpreter | Gear button | Show all | Show paths for the selected interpreter | Reload list of paths**:

[image]

Comment: I'm using a docker-compose python interpreter, and these steps were not sufficient for me. This is what resolved it:
Project Window -> External Libraries -> <virtual interpreter name> -> Remote Libraries
Expand the Remote Libraries, select all directories, right click and delete

Then go to Python Interpreter -> Gear Icon -> Show All -> Click Edit on the interpreter -> OK -> OK through the menus without changing anything.

You will see the Remote Libraries you deleted all come back and everything will reindex